# Matrices that are invariant under a change of basis

Tags: matrices, change-of-basis

Is there a special name or something for when a matrix is invariant under a change of basis, i.e.

$$XAX^{T} = A$$

I'm trying to find what properties $A$ or $X$ have but it's a little hard to search for!

(I can get more specific - $X$ has determinant $1$ and $A$ is symmetric.)

Comment: Hope this helps https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix

Comment: After you get more specific, the question apparently changes a lot: the determinant of $\;X\;$ is one, $\;A\;$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $A$ is symmetric, $X^TAX = A \iff XAX^T = A$ (we can take the transpose of both sides).

A nice way to summarize this property is to say that *the transformation given by $X$ preserves the bilinear form given by $A$*.  That is, for any vectors $u$ and $v$, we have
$$
(Xu)^TA(Xv) = u^TAv
$$
For examples of where matrices like these are of interest, you might want to look into [the indefinite orthogonal group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_orthogonal_group) and the [symplectic matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_matrix).  By [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia), we can think of your situation in terms of some indefinite orthogonal group as long as $A$ is invertible.